# Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context - OOPHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I am just trying to set post_id by constructor and get that id by another function.But that is returning : `Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context` But don't know why this is happening.I had done it many times before but now this goes wrong.

### Below is the code

```
class PostData
{

    private static $instance = null;
    public $post_id = 0;

    public function __construct($post_id = 0){
        if((int)$post_id > 0){
            $this->setId($post_id);
        }
    }

    private function setId($post_id){
        return $this->post_id = $post_id;
    } 
    public static function getPostID(){
        return $this->post_id;
    }

    public static function getInstance(){
        if (empty(self::$instance)) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

### And How i am calling the class

```
$post = new PostData(33);
echo $post->getPostID();
```

But there is error : `Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context`

Comment: You're using `$this` inside a function declared `static`...

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is that you are using `$this` in a static context which is not allowed. By definition a static function is objectless and `$this` references to an object. You need to restructure your class to either be static or not.

How about using this structure:

```
class PostData
{
    public $post_id = 0;

    public function __construct($post_id = 0){
        if((int)$post_id > 0){
            $this->setId($post_id);
        }
    }

    private function setId($post_id){
        return $this->post_id = $post_id;
    } 
    
    public function getPostID(){
        return $this->post_id;
    }
}
```

As per the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php):

> Because static methods are callable without an instance of the object created, the pseudo-variable $this is not available inside the method declared as static.

and again, as per the documentation regarding how you call static properties:

> Static properties cannot be accessed through the object using the arrow operator ->.
>
> Like any other PHP static variable, static properties may only be initialized using a literal or constant before PHP 5.6; expressions are not allowed. In PHP 5.6 and later, the same rules apply as const expressions: some limited expressions are possible, provided they can be evaluated at compile time.
>
> As of PHP 5.3.0, it's possible to reference the class using a variable. The variable's value cannot be a keyword (e.g. self, parent and static).

**Live Example**

[Repl](https://repl.it/repls/AdventurousQuickRom)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you have declared your functions static and you are then using the keyword $this inside the static function.

Remove the keyword *static* from your function to fix:

```
public function getPostID(){
    return $this->post_id;
}
```